# Double bend arrows between nodes in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf

Consider the following MWE:

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}
        % Nodes
        \node[draw] (node1) {1};
        \node[draw, below left=of node1] (node2) {2};
        \node[draw, below right=of node1] (node3) {3};

        % Arrows
        \draw[->] (node1.south) -| (node2.north);
        \draw[->] (node1.south) -| (node3.north);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

which is used to draw:
[image: MWE]

I would like the arrows to be bend twice for instance by writing something like `|-|` instead of `-|`. Is such a simple solution possible? Or do I need something more elaborate?

(I have searched for answers online, but I am obviously using the wrong keywords. Any help regarding useful sections of the TikZ manual is appreciated.)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Something like this :

```
\documentclass{memoir}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Nodes
  \node[draw] (node1) {1};
  \node[draw, below left=of node1] (node2) {2};
  \node[draw, below right=of node1] (node3) {3};

  % Arrows
  \draw[->] (node1.south) |- ($(node1.south) - (0,5mm)$) -| (node2.north);
  \draw[->] (node1.south) |- ($(node1.south) - (0,5mm)$) -| (node3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  % Nodes
  \node[draw] (node1) {1};
  \node[draw, below left=of node1] (node2) {2};
  \node[draw, below right=of node1] (node3) {3};

  % Arrows
  \draw[->] (node1.south) |- ++(0,-5mm) -| (node2.north);
  \draw[->] (node1.south) |- ++(0,-8mm) -| (node3.north);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Untested but couldn't you use `|- ++(0,-5mm) -|` saving some typing? Not at pc so cannot test.

Comment: @daleif yes it also works